# how to parameterize string along with variable name in input json file

Tags: karate

def userName = 'ABC'

```
def input json = {
    "integration": {
        "serviceData": {
            "integrationService": {
                "name": "fld_<tenantID>_stage00.integrations:<integrationName>"
            },
            "gitComments": "Commit made by: ABC"

        }
    }
}
```

In the above json I need to parameterize the user name 'ABC'

If I send 
"gitComments": "#(userName)"

It is checking 'ABC' which is fine
But I need to prefix the String "Commit made by: " And then #(userName) in the input json.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

```
* def gitComments = 'Commit made by: ' + userName
* def json = { gitComments: '#(gitComments)' }
```

Comment: Also by https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions, `"#('Commit made by: ' + userName)"` should also work.